# Yii CGridView filter on button click

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

i have some table in YII that uses CGridView. I want to be able to enter all filtering data and then click on some button and only then send request to server. Right now request is sent every time filter value changes. Is there any native Yii CGridView option to specify that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert this after CGridView widget:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('gridFilter',"   
    $(function(){
        $(document).off('change.yiiGridView keydown.yiiGridView');
        $('body').on('click','.updateGridButtonSelector', function() {
        $('#grid_id').yiiGridView('update', {
                data: $('#grid_id .filters input').serialize()
            });

           return false;
        });
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView and here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7320-how-to-disable-ajax-in-cgridview-or-clistview/

Try with `ajaxUpdate=>'false'` in the widget declaration.